# Dockerize pt-kill as daemon

Tags: docker, percona

I am coverting my infra. to containers. I have a couple daemons that right now live in rc.local but I want to do this the docker way

here are the commands:

```
sudo /usr/bin/pt-kill --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --daemonize --busy-time 30 --kill --print h=db-1,u=master,p=password,P=3306
sudo /usr/bin/pt-kill --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --daemonize --busy-time 30 --kill --print h=db-2,u=master,p=password,P=3306
```

What is the proper way to do this via docker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK Percona doesn't provide an official Docker image for the toolkit but, as suggested by @VonC in his answer as well, you could try using the [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/percona/percona-docker/blob/main/percona-toolkit/Dockerfile) provided in their Github repository, it will give you a base image with the necessary tools installed, including `pt-kill`. To run `pt-kill`, you will need to provide the necessary command when running your docker container, or extend the image by including a `CMD` in your `Dockerfile` with the necessary information. For reference, I build the aforementioned [`Dockerfile`](https://github.com/percona/percona-docker/blob/main/percona-toolkit/Dockerfile):

```
docker build -t local/pt:3.5.0-5.el8 .
```

And was able to using `pt-kill` against a local docker based MySQL database running the following command from my terminal:

```
docker run -d local/pt:3.5.0-5.el8 /usr/bin/pt-kill --match-command Query --victims all --busy-time 5s --print h=172.17.0.2,D=local,u=local,p=local,P=3306
```

I tested it running the following sentence from MySQL Workbench:

```sql
SELECT SLEEP(10)
```

Which produces the following output from `pt-kill`:

```
# 2023-01-01T22:12:33 KILL 16 (Query 5 sec) SELECT SLEEP(10)
LIMIT 0, 1000
# 2023-01-01T22:12:35 KILL 16 (Query 7 sec) SELECT SLEEP(10)
LIMIT 0, 1000
# 2023-01-01T22:12:37 KILL 16 (Query 9 sec) SELECT SLEEP(10)
LIMIT 0, 1000
```

The way in which this container could be run will depend on your actual infrastructure.

I assume by the existence of the `--rds` flag in your command that you are connecting to an Amazon RDS instance.

You have many ways for running containers in AWS (see for instance [this blog entry](https://www.lastweekinaws.com/blog/the-17-ways-to-run-containers-on-aws/), for naming some of them).

In your use case probably the way to go would be using [ECS](https://aws.amazon.com/ecs/) running over EC2 compute instances (the Fargate serverless option doesn't make sense this time), or even [EKS](https://aws.amazon.com/eks/), although I think it would be overkill.

You could provision an EC2 instance, install `docker`, and deploy locally your containers as well, but probably it would a less reliable solution than using ECS.

Just in case, and the same applies if running your containers from an on-premise machine, you will need to launch the containers at startup. In my original answer I stated that in the end you probably will need to use `rc.local` or `systemd` to run your container, perhaps by invoking an intermediate shell script, that will launch the actual container using `docker run`, but thinking about it I realized that the dependency with the docker daemon - it should be running to run your container - could be a problem. Although some kind of automation could be required, consider running your container indicating `always` or `unless-stopped` as the [`--restart` policy](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/start-containers-automatically/).

As you suggested, you could use `docker-compose` for defining both daemons too. The following `docker-compose.yaml` file could be of help:

```yaml
version: '3'
x-pt-kill-common:
  &pt-kill-common
  build: .
  restart: always

services:

  pt-kill-db-1:
    <<: *pt-kill-common
    command: /usr/bin/pt-kill --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --busy-time 30 --kill --print h=db-1,u=master,p=password,P=3306

  pt-kill-db-2:
    <<: *pt-kill-common
    command: /usr/bin/pt-kill --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --busy-time 30 --kill --print h=db-2,u=master,p=password,P=3306
```

We are building the docker image in compose itself: it assumes the existence of the mentioned Percona toolkit `Dockerfile` in the same directory in which the `docker-compose.yaml` file is located. You can build the image and publish it to ECR or wherever you see fit and use it in your `docker-compose.yaml` file as an alternative if you prefer:

```yaml
version: '3'
x-pt-kill-common:
  &pt-kill-common
  image: aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.region.amazonaws.com/pt:3.5.0-5.el8
  restart: always

services:

  pt-kill-db-1:
    <<: *pt-kill-common
    command: /usr/bin/pt-kill --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --busy-time 30 --kill --print h=db-1,u=master,p=password,P=3306

  pt-kill-db-2:
    <<: *pt-kill-common
    command: /usr/bin/pt-kill --rds --match-command Query --victims all --match-user phppoint --busy-time 30 --kill --print h=db-2,u=master,p=password,P=3306
```

In order to reuse as much code as possible, the example uses [`extension` fragments](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#using-extensions-as-fragments), although of course you can repeat the service definition if necessary.

Note as well that we get rid of the `--daemonize` option in the command definition.

In any case, you will need to configure your security groups to allow communication with the RDS database.

Having said all that, in my opinion, your current solution is a good one: although especially using ECS could be a valid solution, probably provisioning a minimal EC2 instance with the necessary tools installed could be a cheaper and simple option than running them in containers.

Comment: Good point. ECS could work indeed.

Comment: And happy new year to you :)

Comment: Happy new year to you too mate.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I will be running these on Ubuntu ec2 with docker installed. Is there a way to spawn 2 containers with compose that passes in the 2 run commands I need?

Comment: Sorry Chris, I just realized that my previous comment was removed. Yes, I think so: I updated the answer with a possible implementation using docker compose, I hope it helps.

Comment: Why don’t I need --daemonize?

Comment: The Docker default entrypoint is `/bin/sh -c` (the `command` provided in the docker-compose file is appended to this one to compose the actual command that will be run). This means you’ll end up in a shell session when you start the container and probably using `--daemonize`, forking the `pt-kill` process to the background and detaching from the shell, will cause docker to terminate your container.  In addition, your container is devoted to run the single `pt-kill` command, so there is no need to fork it in the background. In any case, please, try it, I don't think so, but the option may work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in "[How to use Percona Toolkit in a Docker container?](https://forums.percona.com/t/how-to-use-percona-toolkit-in-a-docker-container/7883/2)", you might need to build your own image, starting from [this Dockerfile](https://github.com/percona/percona-docker/blob/a37d67e37b766f5b4ac6918e65a278919d90c5b8/percona-toolkit/Dockerfile)

The thread mentions The docker image under perconalab ([`perconalab/percona-toolkit`](https://hub.docker.com/r/perconalab/percona-toolkit)) seems to be the same but isn’t.
Maybe [`perconalab/pmm-client`](https://hub.docker.com/r/perconalab/pmm-client) is a better option.